# Exporting Map Layout as PDF - weird distortions

Tags: qgis, layouts, pdf

When I save my map layout as a PDF there are at least two distortions that I notice.

1. The external lat/lon ticks are missing
2. One piece of (blue) text annotation is randomly much smaller.

See screenshot from layout, and pdf

In map layout:
[image]

And exported:

[image]

Comment: Check for differences in DPI between the layout and the export settings. For the blue text, check how it is defined (`map units` should be stable, while `points` will not). Same for ticks, check in which reference units they are defined

Comment: Thanks! Actually switching from pixels to points (which the other text was in) fixed it for the text. Still not sure on the ticks.